# What's the recommended way to update Jetpack Compose UI on Room database update?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Right now, my method of updating my jetpack compose UI on database update is like this:

My Room database holds Player instances (or whatever they're called). This is my PlayerDao:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface PlayerDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM player")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Player>>

    @Insert
    fun insert(player: Player)

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg players: Player)

    @Delete
    fun delete(player: Player)

    @Query("DELETE FROM player WHERE uid = :uid")
    fun delete(uid: Int)

    @Query("UPDATE player SET name=:newName where uid=:uid")
    fun editName(uid: Int, newName: String)

}
```

And this is my Player Entity:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Player(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
)
```

Lastly, this is my ViewModel:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {


    private val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application)

    val playerNames = mutableStateListOf<MutableState<String>>()
    val playerIds = mutableStateListOf<MutableState<Int>>()

    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            db.playerDao().getAll().collect {
                playerNames.clear()
                playerIds.clear()
                it.forEach { player ->
                    playerNames.add(mutableStateOf(player.name))
                    playerIds.add(mutableStateOf(player.uid))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun addPlayer(name: String) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            db.playerDao().insert(Player(name = name))
        }
    }

    fun editPlayer(uid: Int, newName: String) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            db.playerDao().editName(uid, newName)
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, in my ViewHolder `init` block, I 'attach' a 'collector' (sorry for my lack of proper terminology) and basically whenever the database emits a new `List<Player>` from the `Flow`, I re-populate this `playerNames` list with new `MutableState`s of `String`s and the `playerIds` list with `MutableState`s of `Int`s. I do this because then Jetpack Compose gets notified immediately when something changes. Is this really the only good way to go? What I'm trying to achieve is that whenever a change in the `player` table occurs, the list of players in the UI of the app gets updated immediately. And also, I would like to access the data about the players without always making new requests to the database. I would like to have a list of `Players` at my disposal at all times that I know is updated as soon as the database gets updated. How is this achieved in Android app production?

Comment: instead of `mutableStateListOf<MutableState<String>>()`, the recommendation is `StateFlow<List<T>>` via `.stateIn(viewModelScope)` collected as state in the Composable from the ViewModel

Comment: `I would like to have a list of Players at my disposal at all times`. Are you referring to the `playerNames.clear()` call?

Comment: EpicPandaForce thank you, I feel like that's exactly the way to go with `Flow`s and `State`s.

Comment: @Arpit Shukla I don't understand your question. Basically, I would like to have the players cached so that I don't have to access the database all the time. I would like to have them cached in some sort of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

you can instead use live data. for eg -

```
val playerNames:Livedata<ListOf<Player>> = db.playerDao.getAll().asliveData
```

then you can set an observer like -

```
viewModel.playerNames.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner){
    //do stuff when value changes. the 'it' will be the changed list.
}
```

and if you have to have seperate lists, you could add a dao method for that and have two observers too. That might be way more efficient than having a single function and then seperating them into two different lists.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Is using `LiveData` the recommended way though? With Jetpack Compose, I feel like I should be working with `State`s and `Flow`s and stuff. Maybe I'm wrong though. But I know that `LiveData` is used even if you don't use Jetpack Compose.

Comment: I recently undertook an android training programme through google. This was the way they recommended. So.... anyways, if you want the link to the programme, here it is - https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course

Answer (score 0):

First of all, place a LiveData inside your data layer (usually ViewModel) like this

```
val playerNamesLiveData: LiveData<List<Player>> 
    get() = playerNamesMutableLiveData
private val playerNamesMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Player>>
```

So, now you can put your list of players to an observable place by using `playerNamesLiveData.postValue(...)`.

The next step is to create an observer in your UI layer(fragment). The observer determines whether the information is posted to LiveData object and reacts the way you describe it.

```
private fun observeData() {
    viewModel.playerNamesLiveData.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        { // action you want your UI to perform }
    )
}
```

And the last step is to call the observeData function before the actual data posting happens. I prefer doing this inside onViewCreated() callback.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I feel like using `LiveData` is a little obsolete these days.

Comment: In this case I would recommend you to read the Official Android Architecture article. LiveData and Flows are the lates Google modern data-observing patterns =) So, they are lightweight at the same time. RxJava would be to heavy for your purpose...
Here's the "Expose UI" paragraph that advises to use LiveData/Flows 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide/ui-layer